# Ruby audio Library

Tags: ruby, audio, mp3

is there any good Ruby audio libraries that we can build upon?

Need to manage/edit mp3 files!!!

Answer (score 5):

There's an [interface](http://rubyforge.org/projects/id3lib-ruby/) to a C++ mp3 editor, and an active [pure ruby](http://rubyforge.org/projects/ruby-mp3info) project.

Answer (score 2):

[ruby-audio](https://github.com/warhammerkid/ruby-audio)
is the best one right now, it's a wrapper for [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/)

Answer (score 1):

There's also [earworm](https://rubygems.org/gems/earworm) and [icanhasaudio](http://icanhasaudio.com/) which may be interesting...