# Convert audio formats with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, audio

Here are the most common audio formats:

```
.mp3, .wma, .ra, .ram, .rm, .mid, .ogg
```

How should can I convert all of these to `.ogg` using Ruby on Rails? I've had great success using [carrier wave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) for file uploads, and using ImageMagick and Rmagick to convert the most common image formats, `.png, .jpeg, .gif, .jpg` all to `.gif`, so I wonder if it's easy enough to do the same thing with audio?

My development and production machine both run Ubuntu, so I'm hoping there is an app for Ubuntu that can convert files easily, and that there's a nice ruby wrapper for it I can include in my carrierwave uploader.

Comment: Kinda old, but it might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252239/ruby-audio-library /// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576229/ruby-rails-audio-conversion-plugins?rq=1

Comment: Ouch. Last commit was 4 years ago! Still thanks anyway